# SEO: many small pages or only one big?

Tags: seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SEO one longer page vs. several targeted subpages?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7383/seo-one-longer-page-vs-several-targeted-subpages)

Is is better to have just one big page with nice descriptions of products, or just one small page with link to small pages that have, each, one description of one product?

Of course you may think: what a dumb question! Of course the more pages you have the better!

What I mean is: if the pages of your products are very small, and the main page is very small too, maybe google will ignore it or flag it as useless (or whatever) **whereas** a nice and big page has still the potential to be properly indexed by google.

What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very good question. I see that you're representing two extremes;

**Huge amounts of information on one page**

**Almost no information on multiple pages**

Obviously you have already aknowledged that almost no information will lead to a flag, whereas internal links can help. SEO is all about balancing your options with your needs. If you have a ton of products, but only a little bit of information regarding each, instead of going the simple way of having them all listed just once, include some beef to the homepage and add some featured products, sort by this or that, categorize, etc.

In the interest of the soul of the question though, I would definitely suggest using just one page. It might not get high rankings, but atleast you will avoid being flagged by a search engine.