# Which is best for SEO, one long or several short pages?

Tags: seo, content, page

I'm writing the manual for a SaaS and will publish it to our website. Is it better to divide into several smaller pages or one single long one?

Regarding the user experience, I can make it work with both. The question is which is better for SEO?

Comment: Succinct and focused topics per page. Do not muddle your work by being too broad, however, any topic that is not complete cannot compete. Only you can decide this. Some pages will be longer and others shorter. What is important is being organized, focused, creating digestible content and not be overwhelming or underwhelming. It is not the page length that performs well in search, but effectiveness.

Comment: @closetnoc I'm pretty sure page length is a factor. How would you measure "effectiveness"?

Comment: See also (possibly a duplicate): [One longer page vs. several targeted subpages?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/7383/17633)

Comment: You should have 1 page, keep watcing this video until end, it will enlighten you. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lyiikzjg9a0

Comment: We had a question on that very subject a while ago. Length is NOT a factor. Effectiveness is. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/106761/is-word-count-a-large-ranking-factor-for-google/106845#106845

Answer (score 1):

Page length isn't a factor for where Google will rank the page. There are many sites that rank with short pages and plenty of long pages that don't rank. What you are probably thinking of, and where you run into trouble, is [thin content](https://searchenginewatch.com/sew/how-to/2392782/should-we-still-worry-about-thin-content). What @closetnoc said is right, that you want to focus on the completeness and thoroughness of your content.

So, as you think about writing your manual, how many words would it take to completely and thoroughly answer the reader's question? For some subjects, that will require a lot of words. And a lot of words doesn't mean bad UX. You can organize the content with many subheaders and subsections on one page. For other subjects your manual covers, a short paragraph might be enough.

And - remember that it isn't just the words on the page either. Some pages might have few words, but a long video or an image. Those pages can rank and work great for SEO. It is all about answering the question people are trying to answer. So write a page that answers the question better than anybody else and you'll increase your chances for that page ranking.

Comment: Both the short page solution and the long page solution will answer the questions just as good. They will simply answer questions about the features of our SaaS. I read posts at Backlinko that clearly states page length do matter. But when I look at other SaaS, they all have different pages for different features. So I'm a bit confused about which way to go...

Comment: Here is a quote from John Mueller at Google: “Rest assured,” Mueller said, “Googlebot doesn't just count words on a page or in an article, even short articles can be very useful and compelling to users.” Source https://www.wordtracker.com/blog/how-much-does-post-length-really-count-in-seo So - if you can answer a question quickly, that's great! Need more words? Great! Just avoid having pages that people won't find useful or helpful in answering their question.

Comment: Nicely said! Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Keep it on one page don't create multiple pages for the content. Instead, create Jump codes in the article.

Like, in the beginning, create a table of content. Like this

Table of Content

Heading 1

> A
>   B
>   C

Heading 2

> A
>   B
>   C

So, if someone wants to read about only, he'll just click on it and directly will be redirected to the page. In this case, your chances of search engine visibility will be higher due to large content on a page.